# Filtering Nodes in Neo4j Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need to join two different graphs. I would like to apply additional criteria based on nodes in variable path in the join condition. The below query works fine.

```
query1 = 
match(a:iknode)-[*1..2]->(c:iknode)
match(d:flights17)-[r1]-(e:flights17)
where d.alias contains a.name return a,c
```

However, it returns extraneous records. I need to apply some filters on the nodes appearing in [*1..2] part. This also works.

```
match p = (a:fbnode)-[*1..2]->(c:fbnode)
where a.name = 'flights' and ANY (x IN nodes(p) WHERE x.name in ['leaving'])
return nodes(p)
```

I tried the following **which doesn't work**:

```
match p = (a:iknode)-[*1..2]->(c:iknode) 
(d:flights17)-[r1]-(e:flights17)
where d.alias contains a.name and ANY (x IN nodes(p) WHERE x.name in type(r1))
set e.f =c.name
```

How can I rewrite the above query?

One option is to get the results from the first query and then filter the results in a separate query (or python). However, I would like to do it in the query itself. ALL can be used in place of ANY. I would also like to exclude the start and end nodes while filtering.

Comment: It is not clear what you are actually asking, since your 3 queries are doing different things. Can you clarify what you are really trying to do and what exactly "doesn't work" means?

Comment: I need to join two different graphs. I would like to apply additional criteria based on nodes in variable path in the join condition.

Comment: Is there a solution to this? Else, I will not do the filtering. Or probably wont use variable paths. They can be handled in other ways.

Comment: First, you can slice the head and tail nodes from the list using array syntax `ANY (x IN nodes(p)[1..-1] WHERE`, however the planner doesn't actually like that, so it's better for now to just exclude them from the filter logically like `ANY (x IN nodes(p) WHERE x <> start AND x <> end AND <filters>`. As for your question, how does your final query not work? What do you want it to do differently? If you could provide an example dataset, with what your queries return now, and what you want them to actually return, that would help us understand the problem much better.

Comment: Tinkered with match. Took out the d and e nodes and put it before match p. It works if type(r1) is provided as list. Thanks for the start and end thing.

Comment: Tinkered with match. Took out the d and e nodes and put it before match p. It works if type(r1) is provided as list or =. thanks for the start and end thing .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
match(d:flights17)-[r1]-(e:flights17) match p = (a:iknode)-[*1..2]->(c:iknode)  where d.alias contains a.name and ANY (x IN nodes(p) WHERE x.name in ['leaving']) set e.f =c.name
```

This also works for eliminating start and end nodes. nodes(p)[1..-1]